# gVim crash when running autocomplete in ruby file on win7

Tags: ruby, vim

I am using gVim 7.3 and ruby 1.9.2 on Windows7 64bit

after I set the Omni completion func to rubycomplete#Complete,
with the build-in rubycomplete.vim

whenever I call the Omni complete, the vim will crash.

the debug message is
:Access violation reading location 0x00000020.

does anyone know what might cause this problem?
or I should downgrade ruby to 1.8.7 that might avoid this bug?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is because there's bug for ruby plugin in Vim version 7.3.46,
http://www.mail-archive.com/vim_dev@googlegroups.com/msg12221.html

I download the latest build(7.3.107) from Wu Yon's website (http://wyw.dcweb.cn/)
overwrite the executable file in %VIM%/vim73, and the autocomplete works without crash.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that your Vim was compiled with Ruby support?

Check with...

:version

And look for +ruby

Comment: I checked the ruby support by running :ruby p RUBY_VERSION, and :version command show +ruby/dyn